# Cannot open SQL Server profiler file

Tags: sql-server, profiler

**Scenario**

Debugging a failed transaction, I asked the DBA to run a trace on SQL Server. Eventually he send me a `.trc` file.

**Issue**

I use the [`fn_tracegettable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188425%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function to access the trace:

```
select * from sys.fn_trace_gettable('C:\path\to\myTraceFile.trc', default)
```

But I get the following error:

```
  Msg 567, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
  File 'C:\path\to\myTraceFile.trc' either does not exist or is not a recognizable trace file. Or there was an error opening the file.
```

**Facts**

- The SQL Management Studio I am executing the `fn_tracegettable` from runs in my local machine.
- The .trc file is in my local machine.
- Both the server and the local machine run a SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but what is the version of the server instance where the trace was collected, and what is the version of your local instance?

Comment: @Jon Seigel: fact added in my question.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I ran an SQL trace on a remote server and transferred
the trace files to a local directory on my workstation so that I load the
data into a table on my local SQL Server instance for running queries
against.

```
SELECT * INTO ProfileTracesTable
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable('C:\Users\anthony\Documents\SQL_traces\first.trc', default)
```

However, each time I tried, I got the following error:

> File 'C:\Users\anthony\Documents\SQL_traces\first.trc' either does not
>   exist or is not a recognizable trace file. Or there was an error opening
>   the file.

At first I thought the error might be related permission but I ruled this
out since I had no problem loading the .trc files directly into SQL Profiler
or as a file into SSMS.

After trying a few other ideas, I thought about it a bit more and realised
that it *was* due to permissions after all: the query was being run by the SQL
Server process (sqlsrvr.exe) as the user `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` –
not my own Windows account.

The solution was to grant **Read** and **Execute** permissions to `NETWORK
SERVICE` on the directory that the trace files were stored in and the trace
files themselves.

You can do this by right-clicking on the directory, go to the *Security*
tab, add `NETWORK SERVICE` as a user and then select `Read & Execute` for
its Permissions (this should automatically also select `Read` and
`List folder contents`). These file permissions (ACLs) should automatically
propagate to the directory contents (if not, open the *Properties* of the
folder and navigate to the *Security → Advanced → Permissions* tab and *Enable
Inheritance*).

If you prefer to use the command line, you can grant the necessary permissions to
the directory – and its contents – by running the following:

```
icacls C:\Users\anthony\Documents\SQL_traces /t /grant "Network Service:(RX)"
```

Comment: Had the same problem on Server2012 and this solution didn't work. You have to go to the properties of the folder > security > advanced > Permissions tab and click 'Enable Inheritance'.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JohnAlan When a Windows ACE is created for an object, the default is for child objects to *inherit all permissions* from their parent. Since this can be changed, I intentionally used the word *“should”* in my answer. However, I omitted the instructions for enabling inheritance on the presumption that the user would know how (I've now included an extra sentence). Also, the command line includes the `/T` flag to ensure that the ACE recursively applies to all files in the directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you opening the file in the SQL Management Studio?  Use the [SQL Server Profiler tool](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/) instead to open .trc files.

Comment: Unfortunatly, SQL Server Profiler tool is not available in my SQL Management.

Comment: You should install the Profiler tool then. In SQL Management Studio are you connecting to a local DB instance?

Comment: Just FYI you can open trace files like that, the columns & rows show up in the results pane just like a normal query.

Answer (score 1):

You are running query on the database server.  The path in the query is the path on the actual database server and not your local c drive.

Some of your options:
1.  Have the DBA put the file on the server and give you the servers path.
2.  Have a local instance of SQL Server and use the local path on your desktop.
3.  Install SQL Profiler and open it there.

Comment: I edited my question: everything is running in my local machine.

Comment: Where is the actual database server that Management Studio is connected to?  To find out, run the statement: select @@SERVERNAME

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to import .trc file without any errors by opening file into SQL Profiler tool -> File -> Save as -> Trace Table -> SQL Table import option will pop up.

Good Luck

Comment: This is not about importing a trace file really, this is about accessing it in Transact-SQL (particularly, using the `sys.fn_trace_gettable` function).